# Lest FPC and AW_BLog

Tags: extensions, full-page-cache

We are having some problems with FPC and AW_BLOG ... the first blog page is being cached and after then clicking other links (in the blog) they always result in the samen page

Open this link
http://shirtsofcotton.com/blog/sinterklaas-cadeau-overhemd/

and then click a link in the blog section on rights hand; they dont seem to go to another page .... but again show the first open page

We have these set as cacheable actiosn: blog_index_list, blog_post_view

Is there something else we need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Configuration -> System -> Lesti FPC add the following

Add under cacheable actions

> blog_index_list, blog_post_view

Under Uri params add

> tag,identifier,cat,page

Thanks to Gordon Lesti

(works so far)

Answer (score 2):

no Buddy It's working Fine in my browser please Remove your browser cache.[image]

Comment: Also after clikcing several links, tags etc? We had contact with Lesti and they suggested a solution